# Array writes all zeros with Android 4.1.2 on HTC One/Galaxy S4

Tags: android, libgdx

I have two apps in the Android play store which have had no issues up to now. Recently one function has not been working on the HTC one and the Galaxy S4. I have been able to try it out on the HTC one which is running on Android version 4.1.2. The offending code is the following:

```
 public void loadsine(){
     for (int j=0; j<44100; j++){
         double val = Math.sin(twopi*j/44100);
         AndroidAudioDevice.sigBuffer[j]= (short) (val*sinemax);
    }
 }
```

What is does is calculate one period of a sine wave and put the values as a short in an array, twopi and sinemax are previously defined constants, while sigBuffer is the array of shorts 44100 long.

This works fine except on the HTC one and the S4 where the array is filled with zero's. I found I can make it work by wasting a few processing cycles in the loop like follows:

```
 public void loadsine(){
     for (int j=0; j<44100; j++){
         double val = Math.sin(twopi*j/44100); //val between -1 and +1
         AndroidAudioDevice.sigBuffer[j]= (short) (val*sinemax);
         for (int i=0; i<4; i++){}
    }
 }
```

Instead of a useless **for** loop I can also write to the debug window for example. What's going on, is HTC's and/or Samsung's overlay causing issues or is it a 4.1.2 problem. I cannot get a 4.1.2 emulator to work by the way, it doesn't go anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find any details on exactly what `sigbuffer` is, except that it seems to be more an output than an input channel. Your problem is perhaps that the HTC One/S4 is too fast, and `sigbuffer` is a DMA interface, so the data gets overwritten before it is sent to the audio subsystem. Looking at [the API here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/audio/AudioDevice.html#writeSamples(short[], int, int)), perhaps you would be better doing:

```
public void loadsine(){
    short values[44100];
    for (int j=0; j<44100; j++){
         double val = Math.sin(twopi*j/44100);
         values[j] = (short) (val*sinemax);
    }
    androidAudioDevice.writeSamples(values, 0, 44100);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually sigBuffer is just an array of shorts with length 44100. This routine just fills the sigBuffer array with one period of the output signal.    The signal generation routine then copies select values  from the sigBuffer array to the Android trackbuffer in order to actually generate the signal. This works fine also on the HTC one and S4

Answer (score 0):

I've found this as well on the S4. Extremely annoying. Seems like FloatMath still works, although the linter doesn't recommend it as it is slower. Haven't found a better fix unfortunately